# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' in .kv

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, python-3.8

so I'm working with the .kv file and trying to experiment with text inputs
then I was wanting to clear the Text Input
so I wrote this code

Python

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
Builder.load_file("my.kv")
class MyLayout(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def clear(self):
        self.ids.n.text = ""
        self.ids.fp.text = ""
        self.ids.d.text = ""


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

.kv

```
<Button>
    font_size:20
<TextInput>
    font_size:20
<Label>
    font_size:20
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width,root.height
        padding:10
        spacing:10
        Label:
            text:"Name"
        TextInput:
            id:"n"
            multiline:False
        Label:
            text:"favorite Pizza"
        TextInput:
            id:"fp"
            multiline:False
        Label:
            text:"Drinks"
        TextInput:
            id:"d"
            multiline:False
        Button:
            text:"Submit"
        Button:
            text:"clear fields"
            on_press:root.clear()
```

and it throws up this error when i click the "clear field" button

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ids` should not be strings. For example, change:

```
    TextInput:
        id:"n"
```

to:

```
    TextInput:
        id: n
```

Similar for the other `TextInputs`.